# Select text from inside a string after a keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in SQL Server that has a string that looks like this.  I'm trying to get the value of the "some_id" which in this case would '12345678911'.  Any help on how I could get just that numerical value.
I can't seem to get it using the `Substring()` and `Charindex()` functions.

```
 """some_id""=>""12345678911"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", 
 ""anotherString""=>""0""

-- trying to get 12345678911 without the quotes.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT - Heres where my attempt is currently at, and I also did not want that 28 characters hard coded.  It should stop at the first double quote.

```
  select TOP 100 SUBSTRING(col,CHARINDEX('some_id',col), 28) 
  From tableName

  -- RESULT
  -- some_id""=>""12345678911"
```

Comment: Hi Dale - I just edited my original post with where i'm stuck

Comment: So this is an exact example of data in the column, with all those double quotes `"""some_id""=>""12345678911"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", 
 ""anotherString""=>""0""`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it looks like.

Comment: The string format will be same. Right? I mean like ""{some_id}""=>""{Numbers}"". i.e ""some_id""=>""12345678911""

Comment: Hi Mohit, that is correct.  That is the same on all rows.

Comment: Alright, I have just answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given example the following returns the required result. You just create a substring from your starting point and then find the next pair of double quotes, then substring between the starting point and the next pair of double quotes:

```
DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(MAX) = '"""some_id""=>""12345678911"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", 
 ""anotherString""=>""0""', @PatternToFind NVARCHAR(32) = 'some_id""=>""';

SELECT
  SUBSTRING(RemainingString, 1, CHARINDEX('""',RemainingString)-1)
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUBSTRING(Col,StartIndex+LEN(@PatternToFind),LEN(Col)) RemainingString
  FROM (
    SELECT CHARINDEX(@PatternToFind,@col) StartIndex
      , @Col Col -- Comment out this line and uncomment the next 2 to use a table
    --  , MyCol Col
    --FROM myTable
  ) A
) B
```

Which can be combined into a single statement, but you can see that duplicates code, so I find separating it out is clearer:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Col,CHARINDEX(@PatternToFind,col)+LEN(@PatternToFind),LEN(Col)), 1, CHARINDEX('""',SUBSTRING(Col,CHARINDEX(@PatternToFind,Col)+13,LENn(Col)))-1)
FROM (
  SELECT
    @Col Col -- Comment out this line and uncomment the next 2 to use a table
  --   , MyCol Col
  --FROM myTable
) A
```

Answer (score 2):

You could easily convert this into a Function:

```
DECLARE 
    @String VARCHAR(255) = '"""some_id""=>""12345678911"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", ""anotherString""=>""0""',
    @Key VARCHAR(50) = 'some_id""=>""';

SELECT SUBSTRING ( @String
    -- Get the starting position of @Key + @Key's length.
    , CHARINDEX ( @Key, @String ) + LEN ( @Key )
    -- Get the length of the needed value by subtracting the index of the ending double-quotes, from the starting index of @Key + @Key's length 
    , ( CHARINDEX ( '""', @String, CHARINDEX ( @Key, @String ) + LEN ( @Key ) ) - ( CHARINDEX ( @Key, @String ) + LEN ( @Key ) ) )
) AS ParsedValue;
```

RETURNS

```
+-------------+
| ParsedValue |
+-------------+
| 12345678911 |
+-------------+
```

Sample Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetVal (
    @String VARCHAR(255),
    @Key VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN SUBSTRING ( @String
        -- Get the starting position of @Key + @Key's length.
        , CHARINDEX ( @Key, @String ) + LEN ( @Key )
        -- Get the length of the needed value by subtracting the index of the ending double-quotes, from the starting index of @Key + @Key's length 
        , ( CHARINDEX ( '""', @String, CHARINDEX ( @Key, @String ) + LEN ( @Key ) ) - ( CHARINDEX ( @Key, @String ) + LEN ( @Key ) ) )
    );

END
```

Quick edit to show the use of the function in your statement.

```
SELECT TOP 100 dbo.GetVal ( col, 'some_id""=>""' ) AS [Value] 
  FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with below query for given example.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = '"""some_id""=>""12345678911"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", ""anotherString""=>""0""'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, 
                 CHARINDEX('""some_id""=>""', @String)+LEN('""some_id""=>""'),
                 (CHARINDEX('""', @String, CHARINDEX('""some_id""=>""', @String)+LEN('""some_id""=>""')))-(CHARINDEX('""some_id""=>""', @String)+LEN('""some_id""=>""')))
```

Below query will work on the table.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
            VALUES(' """some_id""=>""12345678911"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", ""anotherString""=>""0""'),
                  (' """some_id""=>""23428324"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", ""anotherString""=>""0""'),
                  (' """some_id""=>""8934587349"", ""someother_id""=>"""", ""somethingelse""=>""False"", ""anotherString""=>""0""')
         ) V (String)
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(String, 
                 CHARINDEX('""some_id""=>""', String)+LEN('""some_id""=>""'),
                 (CHARINDEX('""', String, CHARINDEX('""some_id""=>""', String)+LEN('""some_id""=>""')))-(CHARINDEX('""some_id""=>""', String)+LEN('""some_id""=>""'))) 
FROM CTE
```